# Ограничение на данные в записи

Tags: sql-server

Есть таблица с колонками `A`, `B`, `C` типа `int`, необходимо создать ограничения чтобы была возможность заполнить только одну из колонок в записи, остальные должны быть NULL.

СУБД MS SQL Server Ent. 11.0.5343.0 (x64)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно так:

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_TableName_ABC] CHECK (
        (case when A is not NULL then 1 else 0 end +
        case when B is not NULL then 1 else 0 end +
        case when C is not NULL then 1 else 0 end) <= 1
    )
GO
```

Т.е. либо A, либо B, либо C, либо все три `NULL`. Если нужно чтобы одно из A, B или C обязательно присутствовало, то поменять условие с `<= 1` на `= 1`.